# XCode crash when moving groups in Navigator

Tags: ios, xcode9

I am very new here as a user, although I have visited before and always found an answer, but this time I fail to do so...
My problem is that when I create a new project in XCode 9.4 (9F1027a) and then create Groups Without Folder on the Navigator, in order to visually organize my files, I am not able to move it up or down, when I do it XCode closes instantaniously :(...
I know is a silly question and I can live without changing the order of my folders in the Navigator, but is bothering me, and I dont know if this is an XCode problem or it has something to do with my PC... Does someone has faced this before?
Thank u all :)

Comment: I have the same problem, try reporting the bug after xcode crashes. Probably they might fix it faster

Comment: Still happening in Xcode 12.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem only seems to happen when reorganising groups that are directly under the project group - not when reorgansing groups in subgroups.
So, here's the workaround that worked for me.
Create a dummy group without folder directly under the project group.
Move the group whose position you want to change into the dummy group.
Now move the same group out of the dummy group to wheresoever you wish under the project group - et voila!
As I've already stated, this does not (yet) seem to be an issue with subgroups - just groups that are direct descendants of the project group. Hope this helps. V.V.

Comment: Thank u very much!! I have already noticed that this do not happen inside other groups, but I did not used this as a workaround before (daaa!) :) :) It works fine! Althoug I hope they fix this for good at some point...

Answer (score 2):

As previously said it happens only in subgroups.

**My workaround:** move the subgroup out of its parent group, and then move again inside at the desired position.

Hope it helps someone. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and seem to be fixed in Xcode 10 Beta.